# Classic ASP function calls not working on Windows 2008 R2 in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

We are moving our web site from a Windows 2003 server running IIS 6 to a Windows 2008 R2 server running IIS 7.5.  The web site is mostly written in classic ASP but there are a handful of Dot Net apps as part of the web site as well.

Right now I am just trying to get the basic foundational code to work and that is all Classic ASP.  There are a couple of ASP files that are just VBScript pages with a series of functions in the file.  In the main pages there is a  statement embedded near the top of the file.

Later in the ASP page it calls one of the functions from the MyFunctions.asp file.  This works great on the old server but on the new server it acts like it never heard of this function and it gives me an error.  It is a non descriptive 505 error so I don't know what the browser is actually complaining about.

I tried comparing the IIS 7 Web Site setup with another 2008 R2 & IIS 7.5 web server that is working (although it is running a straight dot net web site so that could be the main difference) to see if I could see if anything was different and they were mostly the same.

I read about creating a Classic ASP App Pool that does not use managed code and the pipeline is classic and I set the web site to use that App Pool but that didn't help anything.

I am at a loss and I don't want to nor do I have the time to rewrite the web site in dot net.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing recently. Turned out that the classic ASP code was using server-side includes and these had been disabled in IIS on the the new server. Worth a check.

Comment: Playability, I just found out what my problem was just before you had a chance to reply.  That wasn't my particular problem.  I am about to put the solution as an answer.

Comment: Playability, yesterday when I responsed I was just too happy that I had found a solution to fully comprehend what you were saying. The code I am maintaining is full of server side includes.  I am going to check the server to see how to enable them.  Thanks

Comment: I guess I only partially solved my problem. On 2 test pages I solved the problem but now that I am working on migrating the web site things seem to work intermettantly. Some functions are called and some are ignored. Some code works surrounded by "<% %>" and some don't I created a handlers mapping for asp with the ServerSideIncludeModule and that allowed includes to happen as expected.

I can see the included code when I click on View Code from the right-click menu in the brower.  Some VBScript function just won't work such as response.write("Write Something") and are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was much simpler than I thought.  Most of the classic ASP code is written so that the VBScript is wrapped with "<%" and "%>".  There may be a setting in IIS 7.5 to allow for this but if I get more specific and wrap my VBScript with "" and "" then everything works fine.

If there is a setting in IIS to not be so strict I don't know where it is.  But it is not a problem with me to go through the code and do a simple search and replace.